# mapping code to filter out certain fields form each line in log file

Tags: java, regex, hadoop

here is my java map code for hadoop to filter out certain fields from each line of a log file

```
public class TAnalyser {

public static class TMapper 
   extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{      
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable>   output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException,InterruptedException {

String LogEntryPattern=("(srcip=(?:\\\\d+\\\\.)+\\\\d+)(?:.*)?(dstip=(?:\\\\d+\\\\.)+\\\\d+)(?:.*)?(dstport=(\\\\d+))(?:.*)?(status=\\\\w(?:.*))");
String LogEntryLine=value.toString();
Pattern p=Pattern.compile(LogEntryPattern); 
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(LogEntryLine);

System.out.print(" " + matcher.group(1) + " " );
    System.out.print(" " + matcher.group(2) + " " );
System.out.print("status=close" + matcher.group(4) + " " );
System.out.println(" " + matcher.group(3));
}
}
}
```

here is a sample input file inp.txt

> 2014<>10.100.2.3<><189>date=2014-01-16,time=11:26:14,devname=B39001569,devid=B39001569,logid=000013,type=traffic,srcip=192.168.192.12,srcport=22,srcintf=port2,dstip=10.180.1.10,dstport=3106,dstintf=port1,sessionid=121543,status=close,policyid=196,service=MYSQL,proto=6,duration=10,sentbyte=3910,rcvdbyte=175085,sentpkt=74,rcvdpkt=132";
>
> 2014<>10.100.2.3<><189>date=2014-01-16,time=11:26:14,devname=B39001569,devid=B39001569,logid=000013,type=traffic,srcip=192.168.192.13,srcport=209,srcintf=port2,dstip=10.180.1.15,dstport=206,dstintf=port1,sessionid=123,status=warning,policyid=196,service=MYSQL,proto=6,duration=10,sentbyte=3910,rcvdbyte=175085,sentpkt=74,rcvdpkt=132";

i have given the regex, taken the input as string, compiled and matched the pattern. but I need to filter out and print only those lines that contains "warning" in the status field.

when i run this file in hadoop the following error is shown

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: tanalyser.TAnalyser.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
>       at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1655)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:154)

and I am stuck with it. Any suggestions will be very helpful. Thankyou.

Comment: can you post the entire error log please?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your code for static class declaration ?

public static class TMapper 
   extends Mapper{

Does not seem right. Can you take this out in a separate class and not put this in an inner class and see if that helps?